# sort on object refering element field not working with $group and $project in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting this output:
[image: output]

Sorting on the inner array is not working.  I have the two tables as shown below.

The pages schema is this:

```
const PageSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
     },
     created: {
         type: Date
     },
     position: {
         type: Number,
         default: 0
     }
 });
 module.exports = mongoose.model('pages', PageSchema);
```

The container schema is this:

```
const ContainerSchema = new Schema({ 
    filename: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },pageId: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'pages'
        },
        created: {
            type: Date
        }  
    });
```

For sorting the data I used this code:

```
Container.aggregate(match, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "pageId": "$pageId",
             "id": "$_id",
             "filename": "$filename",
             "position": "$position"
         },
         "containerCount": {
              "$sum": 1
         }
     }
 }, {
     "$group": {
         "_id": "$_id.pageId",
         "container": {
             "$push": {
                  "_id": "$_id.id",
                  "filename": "$_id.filename",
              },
          },
          "position": {
              "$first": "$_id.pageId.position"
          }
          "count": {
              "$sum": "$containerCount"
          }
      }
  }, {
      "$project": {
          "container": 1,
          "count": 1
      }
  }, {
      "$sort": {
          "position": 1
      }
  }).exec()
```

I want the data sort according to the position field in the pages but it's not working.

Comment: Please edit this to have all the code in the code block, not just some of it.

Comment: can you add some documents in the collection?

Comment: @Max, i added the all code.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten to add `position` in `$project`.

> Once you add in `$project` then its available in `$sort`

```
        {
          "$project": {
            "position" :1,
            "container": 1,
            "count": 1
          }
        }
```